# finding out superview's class name

Tags: ios, objective-c

My view controller StartViewController is opened/added (addSubview) by one of two other view controllers (RootViewController or TelnetAddressbookViewController).  Im trying to figure out which of those two is the one that launched StartViewController.

```
NSLog(@"superview %@",self.view.superview.description);
NSLog(@"superview %@",self.superclass);

if ([self.view.superview isKindOfClass:[RootViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"launched by RootViewController");

}else if ([self.view.superview isKindOfClass:[TelnetAddressbookViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"launched TelnetAddressbookViewController");
}

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

The first NSLOG (self.view.superview.description) outputs:

> superview UIView: 0x81d6710; frame = (0 0; 748 1024); transform = [0,
>   1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = >

What its referencing is what I need (0x81d6710) but its class is a UIViewController instead of my custom view controllers.

Comment: have you tried checking the superview of 0x81d6710? I do something similar in an app I wrote and found an additional viewcontroller in the tree. No idea why, but checking the parents parent helped in my case.

Comment: superview.class = UIView & superview.superview.class = UIWindow

Comment: `0x81d6710` is a `UIView`, not a `UIViewController` (or a `CustomViewController`). Can you take care to properly distinguish between `superview` and `superclass`. Note that any object whose class is `CustomViewController` is _also_ an instance of `UIViewController`. The superview of a view has to be a UIView, so will never be a `UIViewController` or a subclass of a `UIViewController`. What do you mean by "view _launched_ a view"? Are you looking for the UIViewController that a view belongs to? Please tidy up the question.

Comment: @HeWas so this viewcontroller (StartViewController) is opened (addSubview) by either RootViewController or TelnetAddressbookViewController.  Im trying to figure out from StartViewController which of the 2 view controllers added/opened it

Comment: @owen, how is it opened? PushViewController? PresentViewController? Some other way?

Comment: addSubview  (extra characters to meet requirements on comment window)

Comment: No. You can't `addSubView` is a UIView method. Not a UIViewController method. It adds UIViews, it doesn't add viewControllers/.

Comment: right well i do viewController.view addSubview.  so are you saying its impossible to get the name of the customer view controller?

Comment: see if my answer helps... but you are seriously confused between views and viewControllers. When you say "My view controller StartViewController is opened/added (addSubview)" ... addSubView adds a _view_ to a _view hierarchy_ from a _superview_ - it does not add a _UIViewController_ to anything.

Comment: regardless its only casting, and the name of the class should be the same.  self.view.superview should still be called the same as the viewcontroller (rootviewcontroller or TelnetAddressbookViewController).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting a property, which does not answer the original question (sorry).  There really should be a way though, even if I had done it by evaluating the frame of the super view.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
NSLog(@"superview %@",self.view.superview.description);
```

You want...

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
NSLog(@"superview %s",class_getName([self.view.superview class]) );
/* or if you want an NSString */
NSLog(@"superview %@", NSStringFromClass([self.view.superview class]) );
```

Comment: this gives me the string "UIView"

Answer (score 1):

If you search the controller of the view, you probably need to do like this: `[self.view.superview nextResponder];`

Answer (score 1):

Untangling your question, I guess you want one of two things... either way the best answer seems to involve a delegate...

(1) the ViewController that created a viewController
The best way to get a hook back into the creating view controller is to make a delegate property in `StartViewController`. Then whichever viewController creates it can set itself as the delegate. Then in `StartViewController` you will have the reference you need.

(2) the UIViewController who's self.view is at the top level of the view hierarchy from the perspective of the view you are in. Then you are trying to find out what subclass of UIViewController that is.

From the view:

```
self.window.rootViewController
```

will get you the top-level viewController of the current screen contents.

Then you can check it's class, for example

```
if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[RootViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"superview RootViewController");

}else if ([self.view.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[TelnetAddressbookViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"superview TelnetAddressbookViewController");
}
```

But this is getting pretty messy, as now your view needs to know about two viewController classes, which breaks MVC.

You are much better of making a delegate for your view, and letting the respective viewControllers handle the delegate methods.

By the way, you shouldn't call one of your classes "RootViewController", it will cause confusion as it's the name of a UIWindow property.